# textAreaフォーカス時に高さを変更するには

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5

Twitterのツイート入力欄のように、マウスカーソルをtextAreaにフォーカスしたときに
textAreaの高さを変更したいです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

jQueryを使って以下のようにしてみましたが、変化ありませんでした。

・javascript

```
$(function() {
  $('#inputTextArea')
    .focusin(function(e) {
      $(this).css('height', '250px');
    })
    .focusout(function(e) {
      $(this).css('height', '80px');
    });
});
```

・html

```
<textarea id="inputTextArea"></textarea>
```

どうしたらよいですか？

Comment: 「変化ありません」 : テキストエリアをクリックします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

同じソースコードで試してみましたけど動作しました。
ブラウザはGoogleChrome/Firefox/Safari/Operaのいずれも最新バージョンで確認しました。
focusin自体はjQuery1.4時代からあるものなので、jQueryのバージョンが古いとは考えにくいですが、念のためバージョンをおしえていただいてもいいですか？

あと、コンソールにエラーなど出ていないでしょうか？

focusinを使用している理由はありますか？focusinは子孫要素にも反応してしまうので、他の要素の子要素になっていた場合動作しない可能性があるので、その影響もあるかもしれません。focusで試してみてはどうでしょうか？

```
$(function() {
    $('#inputTextArea')
        .on("focus", function() {
            $(this).css('height', '250px');
        })
        .on("blur", function() {
            $(this).css('height', '80px');
        });
});
```

Comment: jQuryを読み込む位置を間違えるポカミスだったようです…。すみません、ありがとうございます。